# How to point two urls into one using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to url to a single new url

```
http://www.domain.com/ --> http://www.domain.com/v3/
http://www.domain.com/v2 --> http://www.domain.com/v3/
```

Here's what I did

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^v2/(.*) http://www.domain.com/v3/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/v3/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Redirect 301 /v2 http://domain.com/v3
Redirect 301 / http://domain.com/v3/
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't worked. It just gives me this



`http://domain.com/v3/v3/v3/v3/v3`

Comment: Did you remove your other rules?